# Issue with forwarding runtime QML output to the UI

Tags: qt, qml

I'm working on [this open source project](https://github.com/qCring/QuickVtk), which basically is a live QML interpreter. Since a user's main activity would be to write QML code, I'd like to embed all logs and warnings and such in the application to provide some basic IDE-like functionality. First, I installed a custom message handler via [qInstallMessageHandler](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qInstallMessageHandler) which receives all runtime messages from QML:

```
auto Instance::HandleMessage(QtMsgType type, const QMessageLogContext& context, const QString& msg) -> void {
    std::cout << "handle message: " << msg.toStdString() << std::endl;
    Logger::GetInstance()->addEntry(msg); 
}
```

The `Logger`'s `addEntry` method simply appends the message to a [QStringList](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstringlist.html) property and emits the corresponding `changed()`-signal. On the QML side, I feed that property to a [ListView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-listview.html):

```
ListView {
    anchors.fill: parent;
    model: App.logger.entries;
    delegate: Text {
        text: modelData;
    }
}
```

This works. But the problem appears in combination with dynamic QML object instantiation. The 'magic' part of my application is a call to [Qt.createQmlObject](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-qt.html#createQmlObject-method) which expects some QML source as string and returns the newly created object:

```
function compile() {
    try {
        qmlObject = Qt.createQmlObject(<qml_source>, container, "root");
    } catch (exc) {
        // handle *compile-time* errors
    }
}
```

If 'compilation' fails, control immediately shifts to the catch clause and no new QML object will be created. But if I try to create an object from the following source, the application crashes:

```
function compile() {
    try {
        qmlObject = Qt.createQmlObject("import QtQuick 2.6\nItem { anchors.fill: parent; Rectangle { width: parent.width; height: a.height; } }", container, "root");
    } catch (exc) {
        // handle *compile-time* errors
    }
}
```

The above source is valid, but generates a runtime error. For some reason, the HandleMessage function gets called twice in this specific scenario:

```
handle message: [...]App/root:2: ReferenceError: a is not defined
handle message: [...]App/root:2: ReferenceError: a is not defined
```

And creates a binding loop:

```
handle message: [...]/App/containerview.qml:76:9: QML Repeater: Binding loop detected for property "model"
```

Which is also processed by the custom message handler... You see where this is going: the application gets stuck in a loop and finally crashes.

**My observations so far:**

1. Not forwarding incoming messages to the [QStringList](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstringlist.html) property (just cout'ing them) results in only one single invocation of the custom message handler.
2. Creating the same error **after** construction time causes no trouble:

   ```
   qmlObject = Qt.createQmlObject("import QtQuick 2.6\nimport QtQuick.Controls 1.4\nItem { anchors.fill: parent; Rectangle { id: rect; width: parent.width; } Button { anchors.centerIn: parent; text: \"do something stupid\"; onClicked: { rect.height = a.height; } } }", container, "root");
   ```
3. Not using a list-based property (for example storing all messages in a single [QString](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html) object) also solves the problem but has some obvious disadvantages.

**And finally the question:**
Can someone explain why this happens and how to solve this problem?

Comment: I wonder if it might not be better to have two QML engines, one that runs the IDE and one that runs the content being edited?

Comment: @KevinKrammer That's actually a good point! I'll give it a try, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You let the message handler re-enter. You should not:

```
class Instance {
  QThreadStorage<bool> handlerEntered;
  ...
};

QThreadStorage<bool> Instance::handlerEntered;

void Instance::HandleMessage(
    QtMsgType type, const QMessageLogContext& context, const QString& msg)
{
    if (handlerEntered.localData()) return;
    QScopedValueRollback<bool> roll(handlerEntered.localData(), true);
    std::cout << "handle message: " << msg.toStdString() << std::endl;
    Logger::GetInstance()->addEntry(msg); 
}
```

You must also ensure that the `Logger::addEntry` method doesn't re-enter the event loop nor emit any messages. Most likely, you need to queue the call to the `changed` signal there:

```
void Logger::addEntry(const QString & msg) {
    ...
    QMetaObject::invokeMethod(this, "listChanged(QStringList)",
       Qt::QueuedConnection, Q_ARG(QStringList, data));
}
```

Otherwise, any directly-connected slots, like the QML engine, might do a lot of stuff while the signal - and `addEntry` and `HandleMessage` are still on the call stack.